# Como deletar uma child específica no Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Quero excluir somente a 1ª child (L7jrJ6DtQWrmZsC4zvT) do Firebase através de uma opção em um app para Android. Procurei em vários locais e não consegui encontrar. Só encontrei a opção de excluir a database toda. Alguém pode ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se possível poste seu código. Já tentou `rootRef.child("L7jrJ6DtQWrmZsC4zvT").removeValue();`?

Comment: O exemplo mostra um calendário de jogos. Eu sei qual é a child pois tenho acesso ao console do Firebase. Porém o responsável pela marcação dos jogos não tem acesso ao console, então ele não tem como saber a child. Eu queria que ele tivesse a opção de excluir um jogo da lista a partir de uma seleção no app.

Answer (score 1):

Você terá de fazer uma leitura e depois deletar. Utilize o `limitToFirst()`, passando o valor 1 para pegar apenas a primeira child:

```
calendarioRef.limitToFirst(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String childKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                calendarioRef.child(childKey).removeValue();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Rosário, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Consegui o que queria.

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu. Seria bom se você pudesse postar a solução que obteve como resposta. Assim irá ajudar aos outros que tiverem o mesmo problema :)

Answer (score 1):

Consegui com o seguinte código:

```
Query queryRemoverCalendario = mCalendarioDatabaseReference.limitToFirst(1);                    

queryRemoverCalendario.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

@Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for (DataSnapshot removerCalendarioSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
removerCalendarioSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
 }
}
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
 }
});
```